# How can I download an artifact from Jenkins using the Google Login Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, google-cloud-platform

I recently spun up a new Jenkins instance and installed the [Google Login Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+Login+Plugin) for authentication via Google. I would like to download build artifacts to servers using a shell script, basically curl or wget, but cannot authenticate properly from command line.

I tried the following `wget` command without success.

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=XXXX --http-password=XXXX https://____/job/_____/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/ROOT.war
```

I also tried the same without `http-`:

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --user=XXXX --password=XXXX https://____/job/_____/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/ROOT.war
```

The response is always

```
401 Invalid password/token for user: XXXX
```

I attempted to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244110/use-bash-curl-with-oauth-to-return-google-apps-user-account-data/18260206#18260206) but ran into an issue.

I have seen [this workaround](http://blog.backslasher.net/downloading-artifacts-from-jenkins-with-authentication.html), but it seems like I'd be adding a security hole.

Does anyone have experience with this plugin or in general just downloading from an OAuth-protected endpoint?

Comment: Please try the described method in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632796/jenkins-trigger-a-job-from-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to the comment from user54 for the answer.

Both of my pasted `wget` URLs work as long as I'm using the correct value for password. In this case, I needed to use my user's API Token as described in the answer to another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34634247/317951